# How to generate data based on an existing balanced dataset for binary classification in Python?

Tags: machine-learning

I have a dataset of 100K rows and 100 columns and i want to generate samples based on this existing dataset in order to make the output shape of dataset 10M rows and 100 columns?
Any idea how to do this in Python?
I don't want oversampling methods because my dataset is already balanced.

Answer (score 0):

You should first split your data to train & validation / test and oversample only training data to avoid "bleeding" samples between these datasets

check out these: 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

more about SMOTE 
https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html